# IndexOutOfBoundsException with filtered data adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

Ok - I understand the error I'm getting completely but can't work out how to fix it. I have a `FragmentActivity` that retrieves data from a SQLiteDabase, then three `Fragments` that filter the data.

**FragmentActivity**

```
public static List<Item> values = null;
values = db.getItems();
```

**FragmentOne**

```
private ItemsByCategoryAdapter adapter;
private List<Item> v = FragmentActivity.values;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_items_by_subcategory_main, container, false);

    List<Item> filteredList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    for (Item b : v) {
        if (b.getItemPartner() == 1) {
            filteredList.add(b);
        }
    }

    adapter = new ItemsByCategoryAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, (ArrayList<Item>) filteredList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            adapter.updateIsInMyFavourites(position, true);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

**FragmentTwo**

```
private ItemsByCategoryAdapter adapter;
private List<Item> v = FragmentActivity.values;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_items_by_subcategory_main, container, false);

    List<Item> filteredDistanceList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    for (Item b : v) {
        _count ++;
        if (_count < 15) {
            filteredDistanceList.add(b);
        }
    }

    adapter = new ItemsByCategoryAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, (ArrayList<Item>) filteredDistanceList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            adapter.updateIsInMyFavourites(position, true);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

**FragmentThree**

```
private ItemsByCategoryAdapter adapter;
private List<Item> v = FragmentActivity.values;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.show_items_by_subcategory_main, container, false);

    adapter = new ItemsByCategoryAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 0, (ArrayList<Item>) v);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            adapter.updateIsInMyFavourites(position, true);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 1:
        adapter.updateIsInMyFavourites(info.position, true);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

So sometimes FragmentOne will retrieve 1 record out of 300 (all 300 shown in FragmentThree). The `list.setOnItemClickListener` works fine and updates the listview correctly. But when I put the `onContextItemSelected` crashes within the

adapter on the `data.get(position)` line.

```
public void updateIsInMyFavourites(int position, boolean value) {
    Item itemList = data.get(position);
    itemList.setIsInMyFavourites(value);
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this resolved. Is it something to do with the adapter?

```
private ArrayList<Item> data = new ArrayList<Item>();

public ItemsByCategoryAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Item> d) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, d);
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: At first glance it seems like you are adding those filtered items to the list but are not adjusting their `position` attribute to the new position relative to the list. This could mean you are retrieving their old position and are trying to access an index outside the list bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - how do I adjust the `position`?

Comment: I may be wrong in my last comment, you can't adjust the `position` variable. It's part of the `Adapter` API. Could it be that the position starts counting at `1` instead of `0`, which is normal for an index? Try `Item itemList = data.get(position - 1);` and see if that works.

Comment: Ok - the size of the arraylists are as follows

FragmentOne = 1
FragmentTwo = 30
FragmentThree = 75

The onItemContextSelected works on FragmentOne, but crashes on FragmentTwo with `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 27, size is 1`, and crashes on FragmentThree with `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 74, size is 30`

Comment: It's working on the onItemClickListener. Can it be something to do with the AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo getting the wrong instance of the adapter?

Comment: It does look that way. The error messages you posted in your last comment state `size is <size of the previous list>`, so there must be going something wrong there.